# Forwarding multiple ref in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to forward an object of ref in typescript, but I'm facing an issue to correctly type them.

This are my refs and how I pass them inside my component.

```js
const storyRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
const parcoursRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
const projectRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

const refs = useRef({ storyRef, parcoursRef, projectRef });

...
...

<Navbar ref={refs} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
```

Inside my component I type them this way:

```js
const Navbar = React.forwardRef<
    React.MutableRefObject<{
        storyRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>;
        parcoursRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>;
        projectRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>;
    }>,
    ModalProps
>(({ setShowModal }, ref) => {
```

This is the error I have:

> Type 'MutableRefObject<{ storyRef: RefObject; parcoursRef: RefObject; projectRef: RefObject; }>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<MutableRefObject<{ storyRef: RefObject; parcoursRef: RefObject; projectRef: RefObject; }>> | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject<{ storyRef: RefObject; parcoursRef: RefObject; projectRef: RefObject; }>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<MutableRefObject<{ storyRef: RefObject; parcoursRef: RefObject; projectRef: RefObject; }>>'.

Answer (score 5):

React does not directly support Forwarding multiple ref in typescript. However fear not, there is a real solution called the [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook. You can also create unlimited `refs` to child elements and even functions.

My example has a child component which shows you can easily forward refs to:

- Any html element
- Functions

All with typescript goodness.

### Fully working example:

[image: Edit affectionate-ben-q4ox51]

```js
//Child Component 

//Create your ref types here
export type RefHandler = {
  pressAlert: () => void;
  inputRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
};

const Child = forwardRef<RefHandler, Props>((props, ref) => {
  const submitRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  //Initialise your refs here
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    inputRef: inputRef,
    pressAlert: () => submitRef?.current?.click()
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Child Component</p>
      <input type="text" value="lorem ipsum" ref={inputRef} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => alert("Alert pressed")} ref={submitRef}>
        Alert
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

```js
//Parent 
export default function Parent() {
  const childRef = useRef<RefHandler>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Parent</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          alert(childRef?.current?.inputRef?.current?.value);
        }}
      >
        Read child input
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => childRef?.current?.pressAlert()}>
        Press child button
      </button>
      <hr />
      <Child ref={childRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const refs = useRef({ storyRef, parcoursRef, projectRef });
```

Try creating a typed version for this useRef as well like below and then re-try:

```
const refs = useRef<{storyRef: type, ...restProps}>({ storyRef, parcoursRef, projectRef });
```